# Approach to building numerous variations of Zephyr rots configurations for CI

Tags: continuous-integration, zephyr-rtos, kbuild

Zephyr projects often have dozens of configuration options that enable or disable various pieces of code, or adjust settings.

For example it would be helpful to check that options X and Y compile correctly, but are mutually exclusive (which means two builds), or that various test options not used in production are able to compile and/or run correctly.

Is there an approach that should be used to make it possible to automate building a number of these configurations for various CI purposes?